# Magento Blank Screen on Checkout & Cart with Compiler Enabled

Tags: magento, compilation, wsod

When I run the Magento Compiler process it completes fine and then it's enabled. Everything is fine on the frontend until I add something to the basket, it goes to a white/blank screen, same for the basket page and checkout page.

I've tried uncommenting the ini_set('display_errors', 1); line in the index.php file but still nothing is returned. I've also tried showing errors via the .htaccess file without success.

The website's php limit is 256M, so that shouldn't be an issue because the website is empty at the moment.

Really don't know what to try next to debug this? As it just returns nothing and the error logs are empty (CONFUSED!). I've disabled and removed all the 3rd party plug-ins I've used, that appears to have no effect. And I've successfully used those plug-ins I have on other sites with compilation without any issues.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated! I'm running Magento CE 1.6.0

Comment: If your error logs are empty it probably means you're looking at the wrong error logs.  Try having the system generate something you know should go to the PHP error logs (or Magento exception log) to ensure everything is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked out what was causing the problem!

I've you go to Admin > System > Configuration > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart

And then disable it, then the checkout whitescreen error goes away!

Comment: what is the reason for this?  Getting the same thing.  I wonder what exactly is meant by persistent shopping cart and what I lose by disabling it.  Things were working fine a few days ago

Comment: I believe it is a bug with the Magento Code & it's persistence module. Hopefully it's fixed in newer versions of Magento. I'm afraid I don't know anymore information at this stage.

Comment: Persistent shopping cart means that guests can come back much later than 20 minutes and actually buy what they left in the cart. Increased sales versus negligable speed increase, I'll take the sales and enjoy getting fewer nasty emails from people who have their carts disappear. APC cache and increased optimization in 1.6/1.7 say you can boot it out of your life as one of those needless cart crashing pieces of Magento history.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set it up to use https for checkout/accounts? And if so have you set the base https server to the correct value? If you have told it to use this but not set it up correctly you may get problems.

Comment: I've got https turned off, as we're developing it on a local URL. Use https is set to no for both the frontend and admin. The secure URL is http also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue, although I think I've tracked it down to a 3rd party extension. No errors in either the Magento or server logs, and a whitescreen or 500 internal server error, on add to cart or checkout.

The irritating thing is that although I've found references from the developers saying their plugin isn't compatible with the compiler, it seems work on my test system with the compiler.

Could your case be something to do with file permissions? 
are your includes folder and subfolders writable?

The compiler doesn't seem to return an error is it can't create a new folder for a module, it just doesn't collect that module, maybe you have an in-house modification that's not being picked up?